# Django command giving error

Tags: python, django

I am new to Django and Python having trouble with a Django command.

Before the query, I want to let you know that

1) python is installed in my c drive and the path name is C:\Users\admin67\AppDathea\Local\Programs\Python\Python37

2) The Djangp project is in the D drive and the path name is D://wisdompets

3) My python version is python 3.7.0

In the windows shell I give the command python3 manage.py runserver

However this command is not running in my windows shell. I have tried all combinations such as python370, python37, python 3.7..0 but nothing works and I keep getting the message (see the attachment).

The error traceback that I get in the Windows shell is as below.

> The term 'python3' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spe lling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again. At line:1 char:8 + python3 <<<< manage.py runserver + CategoryInfo : ObjectNotFound: (python3:String) [], CommandNotFoundException + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Please help me resolve this error.

Thanks & Regards Manish

Comment: did you try `python manage.py runserver` ? in windows there are not multiple versions installed. Just try `python`

Comment: It doesn't matter where your python is installed provided it's in the PATH. Did you add it to PATH ? If you're unsure about that you can follow some link to add it to PATH. Or you can reinstall Python but this time MAKE SURE you check the box, "ADD PYTHON TO PATH" checkbox during the installation.(This requires admin privileges)

And I think you're using Power Shell, Try using normal CMD if you're a beginner. The PATH variable is still required though.

Comment: To both Mohit and Vineeth - Yes I did both - tried also python manage.py runserver and also while installing python I added it to the PATH. Still I am getting this error. I am not able to proceed because of this. Please note that my python is installed in C drive while the project is in the D drive. See the paths I have mentioned in my post.

Comment: @Manish Can you access Python shell from the cmd ? By just typing >python in your CMD?

Comment: Vineeth, I will check that and let you know in the evening. Please stay in touch with this post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Python PATH variable is not configured properly. Having Django project and Python interpreter in different locations is not the problem here. The CMD will find the python.exe from the PATH variable defined in the system. If it can't find it then it will raise an error.

Please go to PATH in your Environment variables (Right click on This PC > Properties > Advanced System Settings > Environment Variables 
And check if that exact path of your python.exe(That you mentioned) is there in your PATH. It likely isn't there and that's the reason you're seeing this error.

To resolve it, 
Click on Path variable and edit it. Now add the directory where your Python is installed. i.e "C:\Users\admin67\AppDathea\Local\Programs\Python\Python37" , 
Restart your CMD or PowerShell and Python should now be recognized.

pip also must now be recognized and then 'pip install django==1.11.7' in your cmd, as that is what wisdompets need. If you don't specify the version it will fetch the latest version(Django 2.1 as of now) and entire code will break.

Now in your CMD. 
python manage.py runserver

Hope this helps !

Comment: Thanks Vineet, I tried everything you said but nothing is working. Even in my command prompt when I type python I get the message python is not recognised as an internal/external command. It's frustrating. I am unable to start a project !

Comment: Hello Manish, Are you the administrator of your PC ?

Comment: If yes, then try turning on the **ADD PYTHON 3.X to PATH** by running the python setup file. [here](https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.7.0/python-3.7.0.exe). When you run this setup. look at the bottom and make sure you check that box. Then run the installation, Leaving everything else in default. 

This should fix the problem without fiddling with environment variables.

Comment: You're getting that error because your system is unable to location python.exe when you run it from cmd. Adding to PATH will solve it :)

Comment: Hi Vineet, your solution worked and it is now working. Thanks a lot dude!

Comment: Your welcome :) Mark the post as answer if you don't mind.

Comment: Done. Marked answer as useful as it solved my problem.